# Android ViewPager having WebView is not showing the embeded image with style

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager

I want to show html files of an epub book in webview using ViewPager. The text only files are showing correct but the pages having images are not showing correct(images are not showing). Images will appear only after clicking the zoomin button. After that when I press the zoom out button, the image will gone. I have tried to load an xml file(test.xml) which contains an image. At first time its not loading the image. But after I changed to portrait and come back to land scape, its showed the image.

It is working fine when I tried the same file in a WebView with out ViewPager.

test.xml

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Cover</title>
        <style type="text/css" title="override_css">
            @page {padding: 0pt; margin:0pt}
            body { text-align: center; padding:0pt; margin: 0pt; }
            div { margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="cover1.jpg" alt="cover" style="height: 100%"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I removed the syle property(), it's working fine. Is this the problem with ViewPager?

**Can any one help me to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's causing the issue and you should try to figure out how to avoid this. However, as a temporary workaround you could try to add a WebViewClient to your WebView, that listens for onPageFinished -> and then reload the page once. Something like (NOT TESTED):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url){
        // Called when the page is finished loading
        if(firstTime)
            webview.loadUrl(url); // ONLY call this the first time!!
    }
});
```